# Why Numpy array reshape takes two brackets?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

While learning the Python numpy library I saw the array `reshape` function.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [5,6,7]
c = a + b
d = np.array(c)
e = d.reshape((2,3))
print(e)
```

In the above code why is it that `reshape` takes two brackets?

Why I can't write it like this?

`e = d.reshape(2,3)`

I saw this question anywhere else.

Comment: You _can_, as a matter of fact, write `d.reshape(2,3)`. This is applicable as long as you use the `reshape()` function as a property of the numpy array. If you use the `numpy.reshape(arr, newshape)` function however, `newshape` _must_ be a tuple, as @ggorlen mentioned.

Comment: It's still interesting to know _why_ there are two types of syntax for reshaping in numpy. I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in numpy doc for [numpy.rehsape](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
numpy.reshape(a, newshape, order='C')
```

newshape must be an int or tuple of ints.

And in the doc for [ndarray.reshape:](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html)

```
ndarray.reshape(shape, order='C')
```

*"Unlike the free function numpy.reshape, this method on ndarray allows the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments. For example, a.reshape(10, 11) is equivalent to a.reshape((10, 11))."*

Answer (score 1):

reshape method get shape parameter which it should be tuple as (2, 3)

````
    def reshape(self, shape, *shapes, order='C'): # known case of numpy.core.multiarray.ndarray.reshape
        """
        a.reshape(shape, order='C')
        
            Returns an array containing the same data with a new shape.
        
            Refer to `numpy.reshape` for full documentation.
        
            See Also
            --------
            numpy.reshape : equivalent function
        
            Notes
            -----
            Unlike the free function `numpy.reshape`, this method on `ndarray` allows
            the elements of the shape parameter to be passed in as separate arguments.
            For example, ``a.reshape(10, 11)`` is equivalent to
            ``a.reshape((10, 11))``.
        """
        pass
    ```
````